# For WPF default System Font how can I specify the default system font in a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts

In a resource dictionary, is there a way to declare that the default System FontFamily is what is desired without having to declare a specific System FontFamily (i.e. Segoe UI) ?

If have have the following declaration:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="<some key string>" > xxx </FontFamily>
```

What do I substitute for the xxx to specify the default System FontFamily (System.Media.Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a resource dictionary, is there a way to declare that the default System FontFamily is what is desired without having to declare a specific System FontFamily (i.e. Segoe UI) ?

Short answer: No. Not in XAML.

You could create your resource *programmatically* though:

```
Resources.Add("someKey", SystemFonts.CaptionFontFamily);
```

Or simply use the existing resource(s) from the `SystemFonts` class directly without creating your own resources, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample text..." FontFamily="{x:Static SystemFonts.CaptionFontFamily}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<FontFamily.FamilyNames>
    <System:String x:Key="en-US">Comic San Serif</System:String>
</FontFamily.FamilyNames>
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#composite-fonts)